# Not understanding this setTimeout in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought I understood how the setTimeout method worked, but this is confusing me.

test.html (I'm purposefully loading the test.js file before the jQuery file for demonstration. Let's say the jQuery file is hosted locally).

```
<body>
// ...code
<div id="area"></div>
// ...code

<script src="test.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>
```

test.js

```
$('#area').text('hello');
```

I understand in this case "hello" won't get printed on the browser because jQuery is being loaded after the test.js file. Switching the order of these files solves the problem. But if I leave the order alone, and alter the test.js file, a setTimeout makes it work:

```
function wait() {
    if(window.jQuery) {
        $('#area').text("hello");
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout(wait, 10);
    }
}

wait();
```

In this case the "hello" text gets printed on the browser. But I'm sort of scratching my head because somehow the jQuery file does get loaded. But how?  Why doesn't the test.js file get caught in an infinite loop forever checking to see if jQuery has loaded? I'd be grateful for some insight on the mechanics of what's going on.

Comment: Why do you think it _would_ get caught in an infinite loop?

Comment: Because of the event queue

Comment: It works because when jQuery is loaded, it's variable (jQuery) is saved into the window namespace. So your timeout is checking every 10 ms, if jQuery has been saved yet.

Comment: Because setTimeout in this case could be considered a loose loop, other than a for loop or a while loop will it leave the Javascript thread idle for some time so that it can do other work (e.g. initializing jQuery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the test.js file get caught in an infinite loop forever checking to see if jQuery has loaded?

`setTimeout` works asynchronously. It does not pause the browser. It simply asks it to execute a certain function after a certain amount of milliseconds.

`jquery.js` gets loaded and executed *inbetween* `wait()` invocations.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that the delay _did_ cause the browser to pause. Another question I have is it looks like I'm executing the wait function twice, once in the setTimeout method and again with wait(). Is it running wait twice?

Comment: @MatthewMoon this line of code: `setTimeout(wait, 10)` does **not** execute `wait` (notice that there are no parentheses), it just schedules it to be executed. Initially, `wait()` is executed once - in the last line of your code (notice the parentheses). And then it will depend on the evaluation of `if(window.jQuery)` whether `wait` will be scheduled to run again. If somehow `jQuery` was already loaded at that moment, then `wait` would not run a second time.

Answer (score 4):

There *would* be an infinite loop if jQuery never loaded. But in the normal case:

1. The first time through, jQuery isn't loaded, so we `setTimeout()`
   1a. Other things happen in the meantime, including loading of resources like jQuery
2. 10ms later, we check again.
3. Is jQuery loaded now? If not, set a timeout and go back to step two
4. After some number of retries, jQuery *does* load, and we're off.

The better way to do all of this, of course, would be to

1. Load jQuery first
2. Run your `wait()` function in a `ready()` handler so it doesn't run until it's needed.

```html
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

```js
// test.js
$(document).ready( 
  function() 
  {
     $('#area').text("hello");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without that `setTimeout()` code, when the contents of "test.js" are evaluated the browser will immediately run into the problem of `$` (jQuery) not being defined. *With* the `setTimeout()`, however, the code does not attempt to use the global jQuery symbols until it verifies that the symbols are defined.

Without the `setTimeout` the code fails with a runtime error. The code in the other version explicitly tests for that failure possibility to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

setTimeOut method runs in a separate queue called asynchronous callback. so once the interpreter comes to this line, the code is moved to a separate queue and continues with it parsing(which then executes jQuery.js). After this is executed , it looks for items the asynchronous queue to check if the timeout is completed and then executed method inside setTimeout. By this time jQuery.js is already loaded.

More on this
https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't realize it put it in a separate queue allowing the browser to continue parsing. That's where my thinking was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not pre-compiled. It's working "on the fly".

You can add code on the fly, whenever you want, and this includes loading whole libraries. Once the browser loaded an external JS file it parses it, and it's all ready to use.

So if you wait for jQuery, and do have the proper code to load it, it will eventually be loaded by the browser and work.